# Iterate over POSIXlt in R

Tags: r

Imagine I have an input vector of `POSIXct` objects:

```
times.input <- c(
  as.POSIXct('2013-01-01 00:00:00', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2013-01-01 00:00:01', tz='GMT')
)
class(times.input)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Some of the functions (like `round` or `trunc`) transform `POSIXct` to `POSIXlt`:

```
unique.dates <- unique(trunc(times.input, 'days')))
class(times.rounded)
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Then, if we try to iterate or `lapply` this object, strange things happen:

```
lapply(X=unique.dates, FUN=print)
# [1] 0 0
# [1] 0 0
# [1] 4 4
# [1] 1 1
# [1] 0 0
# [1] 113 113
# [1] 2 2
# [1] 0 0
# [1] 0 0
```

It seems like `POSIXlt` is stored internally vertically as a list of vectors, 
and iteration goes over internal structure instead of iterating over each object.

I know that converting to `POSIXct` helps in this case, because `POSIXct` is stored as an integer internally, but I consider this solution to be ugly.

So my question is: given a `POSIXlt[2]` data input, how to perform for loop or `lapply` over `POSIXct` objects?

Comment: Can you clarify, what you actually want to do?  `print(times.rounded)` works just fine for your example. Otherwise, the generic advice is convert to `POSIXct`, which is probably the least "ugly" solution.

Comment: Why is ugly to coerce to POSIXct? and I don't' understand your last question , given a POSIXlt...hos to loop over what ?

Comment: I substituted complex function with `print` just to indicate the problem. In real world some function like `downloadDataForDate` is used.

Comment: I consider coercing to `POSIXct` as ugly because it is an unnecessary computation, given large enough data this computation can take measurable amount of time.

Comment: Please _measure_ before making such conjectures. POSIXct is a more compact storage form **of the very same information** and all the relevant computational time is most likely passed on **parsing from string representaton**.

Comment: Guys, coercing performance is not an issue here. Let's pretend that we argue about some other class `XXX`, which doesn't have `XXXct` counterpart. This class is implemented as list, and we want to use iteration and/or `*apply`-family functions to a set of objects of this class. What would be our steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening cause `lapply` works on list and you're right about storing, after `help("DateTimeClasses")`:

> Class "POSIXlt" is a named list of vectors (...)

If you really need to work with `POSIXlt` I propose convert to list, e.g.:

```
times.input.L <- split(times.input, seq_along(times.input))
lapply(times.input.L, print)
[1] "2013-01-01 01:00:00 CET"
[1] "2013-01-01 01:00:01 CET"
```